# error with string variable

Tags: string, matlab

I'm trying to use a string variable as input to an xml function. When I use this command:
`name2_node(i).setTextContent('truck');`

there is no error. But when I replace it with:

`name2_node(i).setTextContent(type(i,1));`

an error occurs like this:

> No method 'setTextContent' with matching signature found for class
>   'org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementImpl'.

The variable **type** is a string array. In fact when I type `type(i,1)` in command window the result is:

```
ans = 

  string

    "truck"
```

What part am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. use a different variable name, [`type`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/type.html?searchHighlight=type&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) is a built in function which tells you the variable type, hence why it shows "string" in the output.
2. Then access the cell array of strings with curly braces

   ```
   vehicletypes = {'car'; 'truck'; 'van'};
   name2_node(i).setTextContent(vehicletypes{i,1}); % For i=2, this passes 'truck'
   ```

Comment: thanks a lot. using curly braces solved the problem.